# Two different conclusions about continuity implying convergence of sequences - are both true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

I used to think the following was true:

> > $f$ is continuous, IFF the following holds: Given any sequence in its domain that converges, a corresponding sequence in its codomain converges.

But I recently saw a similar statement:

> > if $f$ is continuous and $x_n$ converges to $x_0$ in the domain of $f$, then $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

My question is whether both statements are true.  And if so, why is the second statement not an IFF, like the first one is?

Thanks.

**EDIT**  Also, I'm trying to think of a good counter example for the second statement where we have $f(x_n)$ converging to $f(x_0)$ but either $x_n$ does not converge to $x_0$, OR $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Both are IFF statements in a metric space but not in general topological spaces.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought, but  *WHY is the second one NOT an IFF*?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm just working in Euclidean space.  thanks

Comment: Let $x_0=0.$ Let $ f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$. Let $x_n=n$. Then $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ and $ f(x_n)$ converges to $0=f(x_0)$ but $x_n$ does not converge to $x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

It becomes an IFF if you require that **for every** sequence $x_n$ converging to $x_0$, $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

Both statements are true.

Comment: right right, that's what I meant!  Thanks  I'll edit.

Comment: Yes I understand both statements are true.  But my question is *WHY is the second one NOT an IFF*?

Comment: also i'm not seeing a counter example easily...?  i'm probably missing something.

Comment: @GReyes OP did not say whether he is working a metric space or not. In a general topological space sequential continuity is not equivalent to continuity.

Comment: I'm just working in Euclidean space.  Sorry guys for not specifying that.

Comment: The 2nd statement  as it appears now, is not IFF. The proposer has added a paragraph labelled EDIT so it may be that the Q has been changed.

Comment: I assumed the context was the Euclidean space,where sequential continuity is equivalent to continuity. In that context, is always true that if $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $x_n\to a$ then $f(x_n)\to f(a)$. For the reverse to be true, you need to impose the condition on all possible sequences. For example, take $f(x)=1$ for rational $x$ and $0$ for irrational $x$. Then, along any sequence $x_n\to 0$ consisting of rational numbers, $\lim f(x_n)=1=f(0)$ but  $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$ since for any sequence $x_n\to 0$ of irrational numbers, $\lim f(x_n)=0\neq f(0)$.